# MSSQL 2008R2 TSQL Calculate Ratio Percentage on Total Column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

MSSQL 2008R2

Say I have two columns, "Name" and "Total"

```
Name    Total
Team1   2556.54
Team2   2204.77
Team3   2141.64
Team4   1401.37
Team5   1220.77
Team6   1149.92
Team7   1130.62
Team8   1073.69
Team9   1059.66
Team10  1028.52
Team11  970.02
Team12  947.85
Team13  886.93
Team14  788.09
Team15  730.99
```

Is it possible to calculate and identify the rows belonging to the TOP 10%, BOTTOM 15% from the Total Column?

Where 10% and 15% are variables.

if so how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are loking for Select top 50 Percent Name,Total From <Table> Order By Total Desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Top 10%
SELECT TOP (@top) PERCENT Name, Total
FROM Teams
ORDER BY Total DESC

--bottom 15%
SELECT TOP (@bottom) PERCENT Name, Total
FROM Teams
ORDER BY Total ASC
```

Comment: I apologise, but I forget to mention in the question that 10% and 15% are variables.

Comment: @Mountaineer see my new answer

Comment: @Mountaineer never mind, it was an overkill. That keepts it simple.

Answer (score 1):

I apologise, but I forget to mention in the question that 10% and 15% are variables.

EDIT

It seems it you place the variable in parentheses it works

```
SELECT top (@top)
```